# Trouble implementing Undo/Redo in my MVVM based application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having trouble implementing any kind of undo redo system in my application. I would like some guidance on how I need to do it in my case. I have read about the Memento Pattern, which seems to be the most used, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

First of al, my application is built using MVVM, so all actions from the UI are bound to a method that returns an ICommand. Here's an example:

```
public ICommand PlaySoundCommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand(PlaySound); }
}

private void PlaySound()
{
    methods.playSound(soundPath, selectedSound);
}
```

So the PlaySoundCommand is bound to the UI control and it executes the change that needs to be made to the data. `DelegateCommand` looks like this:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action action;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action_)
    {
        action = action_;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

When that is done, whichever method was called using the UI does his thing. There is for example a method called `addGroup()` which will add a group, obviously, to a `ObservableCollection<GroupModelView>` which holds all groups. That collection is declared like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> groupModelList = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> GroupModelList
{
    get { return groupModelList; }
    set
    {
        groupModelList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupModelList");
    }
}
```

Inside that `GroupModel` there is also another viewmodel of another object type that holds a list that belongs to that certain group. (It also holds other properties but those are simple strings and floats)

How would I go about implementing an undo/redo system for this?

If you need more code, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: An undo/redo system requires that *all* actions are performed as `ICommand`s. Each `ICommand` object is then `Push`ed into a [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) collection. To undo, you `Pop` the last `ICommand` from the collection and perform the opposite action. However, this sounds simpler than it actually is, as you also need to store all relevant parameters and possibly separate undo actions for each `ICommand`. Please search online for further information as this subject is widely covered and not really suitable for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A good source http://www.wpftutorial.net/UndoRedo.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. If I'd have to do this for a textbox with databinding, which doesn't trigger by command but just changes the text from the source directly. How would I go about that?

Comment: What the ... 99% of your question is nothing but filler.  What does a command that plays a sound have to do with undo/redo?  What is this I don't even

Comment: It's just an example of how my UI "talks" to the code. All UI controls (especially buttons) are bound to these types of command. I am showing the general way my application works so you can possibly help me out by saying what I would need to do to get the undo/redo working